ros2 humble installation issue
i try to install the ros2 on ubnutu 22.04 using
sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop

    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pil.imagetk : Depends: python3-pil (= 9.0.1-1ubuntu0.2) but 9.0.1-1ubuntu0.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

i try this from  the ROSANSWERS
Solution Install aptitude:
$ sudo apt-get install aptitude




$ sudo aptitude install ros-humble-desktop

You should see a list of dependencies and a proposed action:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-humble-desktop : Depends: ros-humble-action-tutorials-cpp but it is not installable
      <Dependencies listed>

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:

         ros-humble-desktop [Not Installed]


The first prompt reminds us that there are a lot of things that are not installed let us choose No:
Type: N

The second prompt may ask us to upgrade or downgrade something, this is what we need.
Type: Y



It will then ask you to install ROS files:
 Type: Y


After that ROS should install automatically.

If however, it presents the following message "-O APT:::GET::Fix-Missing=true" you must execute:
$ sudo apt-get --fix-missing

Repeat Steps 1-5 until you no longer receive this error message.
But i repeat the steps 1-5 many more times not worked for me anyone give the solution to that
